# xml2js parser ignores the empty string in an array resulting in array size change

Tags: node.js, typescript, xml2js

xml below to be parsed:

```
<ENVELOPE>
<ABC>
    <DEF>apple</DEF>
    <GHI>4</GHI>
    <JKL>85</JKL>
</ABC>
<MNO>add</MNO>
<PQR></PQR>
<STU></STU>
</ENVELOPE>
```

and response after parsing:

```
{
```

"ENVELOPE": {
    "ABC": {
      "DEF": "apple",
      "GHI": "4",
      "JKL": "85"
    },
    "MNO": "add"
  }
    }

The other two tags has been discarded by the xml2js parses. But i need it there to be empty atleast. Have tried using options of the parser but no luck yet

Here is my code to get the parser:

```
private getParser() {
let nameToLowerCase = (name: string): string => {
  return name.toLowerCase();
}

let options: xml2js.Options = {
  attrkey: '_',
  charkey: '$',
  explicitCharkey: true,
  emptyTag: null,
  normalize: true,
  normalizeTags: true,
  explicitArray: false,
  trim: true,
  tagNameProcessors: [nameToLowerCase],
  attrNameProcessors: [nameToLowerCase]
};

return new xml2js.Parser(options);
```

}

Comment: I get pretty different output using [`xml2js`](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) using its default settings, so either you're passing it particular options that are causing this, or you're using another package. Can you show the gist of your code?

Comment: Using that exact code (minus the TS annotations), I get `{"envelope":{"abc":{"def":{"$":"apple"},"ghi":{"$":"4"},"jkl":{"$":"85"}},"mno":{"$":"add"},"pqr":null,"stu":null}}` as a result.

Comment: It has to be this output. But i m not getting the same. the value with null is not shown

Comment: Which version of `xml2js` are you using (`npm ls xml2js`)? I'm using 0.4.17.

Comment: @robertKlep yes the same version. god damn it was my removeUnwantedTags doing the ugly job. No issue in the parser as such. Thanks for the support